# ModelForm right approach for editing database record?

Tags: python, django, web, django-forms, modelform

Can someone help me with fixing Django ModelForm?

This particular code can add new item to database as expected, but when I'm trying to edit db record - It just add new record, instead of updating old. I'm quite new in Django framework.

**views.py:**

```
def manage(request, item_id = None):
    t = get_object_or_404(Hardware, id=item_id) if item_id else None
    form = Manage(request.POST or None, instance=t)

if t:
    if form.is_valid():
        #form.save()
        hostname = form.cleaned_data['hostname']
        cpu = form.cleaned_data['cpu']
        os = form.cleaned_data['os']
        ram = form.cleaned_data['ram_total']
        storage = form.cleaned_data['storage']
        hostdata = Hardware(
        hostname=hostname,
        cpu=cpu,
        ram_total=ram,
        os=os,
        storage=storage,
        lock_state=t.lock_state, # because in edit operation we shouldn't change it.
        lock_date=t.lock_date, # because in edit operation we shouldn't change it.
        locked_by=t.locked_by) # because in edit operation we shouldn't change it.
        hostdata.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:index'))
elif not t:
    if form.is_valid():
        hostname = form.cleaned_data['hostname']
        cpu = form.cleaned_data['cpu']
        os = form.cleaned_data['os']
        ram = form.cleaned_data['ram_total']
        storage = form.cleaned_data['storage']
        current_user = request.user
        user = User.objects.get(id=current_user.id)
        hostdata = Hardware(
        hostname=hostname,
        cpu=cpu,
        ram_total=ram,
        os=os,
        storage=storage,
        lock_state=0,
        lock_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
        locked_by=user)
        hostdata.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:index'))

return render(request, 'hardware/edit.html', {'form': form})
```

**models.py:**

```
class Hardware(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None)
    os = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None)
    cpu = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None)
    ram_total = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None)
    storage = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None)
    lock_state = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    locked_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    lock_date = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
    alive = models.BooleanField(default=0)

class Meta:
    db_table = "hardware"

def __str__(self):
    return self.hostname
```

**forms.py:**

```
class Manage(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Hardware
        fields = ['hostname', 'os', 'cpu', 'ram_total', 'storage']
```

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^manage/new/$', views.manage, name='add'),
url(r'^manage/edit/(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.manage, name='edit')
```

**template:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Save!" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already retrieved the instance `t` in the first line of your view. The code below will always create a new instance (unless you specify the `pk` parameter):

```
 hostdata = Hardware(...)
 hostdata.save()
```

Simply do this instead:

```
 if t:
     if form.is_valid():
         t.hostname = form.cleaned_data['hostname']
         t.cpu = form.cleaned_data['cpu']
         ....
         t.save()
```

However, you really should rely on the `save` method provided by the `ModelForm` as the other answers suggested. Here's an example:

```
 def manage(request, item_id=None):
     t = get_object_or_404(Hardware, id=item_id) if item_id else None

     # if t is None, a new object will be created in form.save()
     # if t is an instance of Hardware, t will be updated in form.save()
     form = Manage(request.POST, instance=t)

     if form.is_valid():
         form.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:index')

     return render(request, 'hardware/edit.html', {'form': form})
```

You also specified `fields` in your form:

```
fields = ['hostname', 'os', 'cpu', 'ram_total', 'storage']
```

These are the fields which will be set or updated when you call `form.save()`.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I make separate behaviors with that approach like 1. When I create new record - I'm using some default values for db rows which are not present in form. 2. When I'm using edit form - do not change these values and leave as is in database?

Comment: Only the fields specified in `fields = [...]` are updated. In your form, `lock_state`, `lock_date`, `locked_by` will never be updated by the form, even if data exists in request.POST.

Comment: For default values in the creation of a new model, you have 2 options: 1. set the default value in models.py, or 2. use `hardware = form.save(commit=False)` and modify `hardware` to suit your needs before calling `hardware.save()`.

Comment: I was able to make fixes to db default fields for new item creation, but have noticed following bugs:  1. When you open any form (create/edit) - "This field is required." errors are shown always. 2. Edit form for some reason not populating with the data from database.  I have used view from your example and here is my fixed parts of the Model: `locked_by = models.ForeignKey(User, default=lambda: User.objects.get(id=1))
    lock_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())`

Comment: The error messages you see are caused by `form.is_valid()`. You need to handle http post and get separately. An http get should render the page without calling `form.is_valid()`. I have added a sample implementation at https://gist.github.com/derekkwok/c0b8cdb32b8333364318

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this - using [`update_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save) - should work:

```
def manage(request, item_id = None):
    t = get_object_or_404(Hardware, id=item_id)
    form = Manage(request.POST or None, instance=t)

if t:
    if form.is_valid():
        #form.save()
        t.hostname = form.cleaned_data['hostname']
        t.cpu = form.cleaned_data['cpu']
        t.os = form.cleaned_data['os']
        t.ram = form.cleaned_data['ram_total']
        t.storage = form.cleaned_data['storage']   
        t.save(update_fields=['hostname', 'cpu', 'os','ram','storage'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:index')) 
........
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Class Based View, which in it's simplest looks like:

```
from django.views import generic
class HardwareEditView(generic.UpdateView):

    template_name = "hardware.html"
    form_class = Manage
```

You will have to add get_absolute_url to the model.
Generic class based views are exactly for this standard create/update/view common tasks.

Comment: Yes, I tried before Class based views, but wasn't able to populate edit form with data from database. Will try again.

Comment: I takes sometime to get used to it, but once you do you will not look back. Set a form, a queryset, a template and oops ... it's working.